# How can the shortest distance between 2 points be a curve?

Tags: geometry

please help me with my question!! I have been asked this question by my teacher and NO NONE knows

Comment: I think this really belongs on Math SE rather than here (I have flagged this for migration, so there is no need for you to repost it there). It would help if you provided a bit of context for your question. Also have a look at our [tour] - you can edit your question to remove the "please help" sentence (you might also want to correct the spelling of "no one" while you're at it).

Comment: Can you provide some background?

Comment: Are you aware that there is more than one (infinitely, actually) ways to define the notion of *distance*?

Comment: Perhaps you are on a curved surface?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not constrained by anything and are in "normal space" with $x,y,z$ coordinates, then the shortest distance between two points is a straight line (in the typical sense of "straight").

If you're on a sphere, and have to stay within the surface of the sphere, then the shortest distance between two points on the sphere is an arc that lies on the great circle defined by those two points.  (A great circle is like an equator on an idealized Earth; the radius of all great circles is the same as the radius of the sphere).

Let's say we have two points: the North pole, and a point on the equator of a sphere of radius $r$.  The "straight-line" distance between the two points is
$\sqrt{2}r \approx1.414r$.  The distance on the surface of the sphere is $\pi r/2 \approx 1.57r$.

That's one example.  As suggested in the comments of your question, there are many other examples.